# Can typescript Objects be extended

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `baseMenu` object in which the dishes that are common across all the branches are present. I also have a city based menu `chicagoMenu` and `houstonMenu` that are specific to Chicago and Houston respectively.

Is it possible in typescript for one object to extend all the properties and their values of another object. In my case, can `chicagoMenu` and `houstonMenu` extend the properties of `baseMenu` object.

The requirement is that when I iterate over the city based menu like `chicagoMenu`, it should contain all the dishes of `basemenu` and `chicagoMenu` as well

```
let baseMenu = [ 
  {dish : "fried chicken", price :"3$"},
  {dish : "pepsi", price :"1$"},
  {dish : "burger", price :"2$"},
]

let chicagoMenu = [
  {dish : "pizza", price :"3$"},
  {dish : "hot dog", price :"1#"}
]

let houstonMenu = [
  {dish : "sandwich", price :"2$"},
  {dish : "Orange juice", price :"2$"}
]
```

Comment: Your menus are not "objects" with "properties", they're **arrays** with **elements**. (Technically, they are objects, but not with named properties). TypeScript has nothing to do with this. You just want JavaScript array concatenation. All the objects in your arrays have the same type and the same two properties (`dish` and `price`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup you can easily do it like this

```
let baseMenu = [ 
  { dish: "fried chicken", price: "3$" },
  { dish: "pepsi", price: "1$" },
  { dish: "burger", price: "2$" },
];

let chicagoMenu = [
  ...baseMenu, // Include all dishes from baseMenu
  { dish: "pizza", price: "3$" },
  { dish: "hot dog", price: "1#" },
];

let houstonMenu = [
  ...baseMenu, // Include all dishes from baseMenu
  { dish: "sandwich", price: "2$" },
  { dish: "Orange juice", price: "2$" },
];
```

The spread operator '...' is used to include all the dishes from 'baseMenu' in the 'chicagoMenu' and 'houstonMenu'.In this way, when you iterate over chicagoMenu or houstonMenu, they will contain all the dishes from baseMenu as well as their own specific dishes.
If you want to read more about this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
You can refer to this link

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is not just about Typescript but Javascript.

The Typescript part... You should set a type for base menu and since the others objects are the same type, I mean, they share the same properties, you can use this type as well.

```
type BaseMenu = {
  dish  : string, 
  price : string
};
```

As for the Javascript part, if you want to iterate over all objects, you should merge them into a single array.

```
const allMenus : BaseMenu[] = [...baseMenu, ...chicagoMenu, ...houstonMenu]
```

The three dots before each object in the array means all their properties will be copied to the array.